# How to check if ContactGroup exists

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I would like to share a gsheet with colleagues and they should be able to run a script to copy contacts from the sheet to own contacts. 
I would like to create a MyCorp1 ContactGroup and add contacts to that. I want to check if the user has already created this group. Could not find the way to check this. is there a workaround? Unfortunately, if I try to create group twice or more it will create duplicates.

Thanks in advance
Gabor

```
function addCont(row){ 
var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(row[1], row[0], row[5]);
//if not empty
if (row[3] != "") {contact.setMobilePhone(row[3]);}
if (row[4] != "") {contact.setWorkPhone(row[4]);} 

 var myGroup = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('MyCorp1');
 myGroup.addContact(contact); 
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function delcreateGRP(){ 
 var myGroup = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('MyCorp1');
 myGroup.deleteGroup();  
 ContactsApp.createContactGroup('MyCorp1');
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function copyContacts() {
var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
// This is the Request Spreadsheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(REQUEST_SPREADSHEET_ID);
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// Fetch all the data from the Request Spreadsheet
// getRowsData was reused from Reading Spreadsheet Data using JavaScript Objects 
//var data = getRowsData(sheet);
//var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
Logger.log('datalength: ' + data.length);
for (var i = startRow; i < data.length; ++i ) {
var row = data[i];
row.rowNumber = i + 2;
addCont(row);
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `.getContactGroup('Group Name')` method returns null if there is not a contact group with the given name, you can use an if/else statement to do your work.

```
var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Group Name');

if(group) {
  //do something if the group exists
} else {
  //do something if the group DOES NOT exist
}
```

Here is the documentation I am using: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getContactGroup(String)